# Using replace with regular expressions - VBA

Tags: regex, vba, format

I would like to format a text. I mean something like this:
I'd like to transform this:

```
"something'text between apostrophes'text"
```

into

```
"something 'text between apostrophes' text"
```

I want to add spaces from both sides, but keep te string in '' the same. 
I tried to do it like this:

```
  Arkusz1.Cells(1, 1).Replace What:="'*'" Replacement:=" '*' "
```

But its result is:

```
"something '*' text"
```

`Arkusz1.Cells(1,1)` contains the `string` I want to replace. Is it possible to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
('[^']+')
```

and replace by this:

```
" $1 "
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f9kwXV/1/)

Comment: The OP is about VBA, not VB.NET.