# Wildcards in vba string variable

Tags: excel, vba, string, variables, replace

I would like to know if wildcards in simple VBA replace function work.
So i have a string variable, let's say:

```
str = " Lorem Ipsum 3.07 EUR Dorum"
```

I am required to remove this part "3.07 EUR". I definitely know the amount, but not the currency
The code i tried which did not worked:

```
str1 = Replace(str, " 3.07 ???", "")
```

I know it works when I make replacement in cell or a range as I have a part of code that does it. Is there any difference in replacement in cell and replacement in a string variable and I am just doing it wrong?

Comment: What keeps you from checking it out yourself?

Comment: I would not post a question if i didn't check :) It does not work for me, but i hope i am just doing it incorrectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using replace with regular expressions - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702510/using-replace-with-regular-expressions-vba)

Comment: The only one I found is Regex. But it does a lot of mess in a code rather then simple replace and require adding reference.

Comment: The documentation for `Replace` doesn't mention any wildcards. Regarding RegEx, you can set up a function `RegExReplace(input, pattern, replacement)` and still have a one-liner in your code. The requirement to add a reference can be circumvented by late-binding the RegEx objects. (Still requires the dependencies to *be installed*, though.) And I agree, RegEx in VBA are kinda complicated. But, still, they present a solution that doesn't require hard-coding all expected currency identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular expression (this assumes you know the number, as you stated):

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox RemoveString(" Lorem Ipsum 3.07 EUR Dorum", "3.07")
End Sub

Function RemoveString(s$, num$)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = num + "\s+[A-Z]{3}"
        RemoveString = .Replace(s, "")
    End With
End Function
```